# Problem with stored procedure inserting date format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have stored procedure that needs to insert date into table. But when I try to execute it through graphical interface with YYYY-MM-DD format I'm getting error saying:

> incorrect syntax near '-'.

I also tried with apostrophe but then I'm getting error converting data type numeric to int. I checked if my table has right format, and it does. Any idea what is happening?

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[UbaciVlasnika]
    (@ImeVlasnika NVARCHAR(50),
     @PrezimeVlasnika NVARCHAR(50),
     @DatumRodjenja DATE,
     @JMBG INT,
     @VlasnikID INT OUTPUT)
AS
    INSERT INTO Vlasnik 
    VALUES (@ImeVlasnika, @PrezimeVlasnika, @DatumRodjenja, @JMBG)

    SELECT @VlasnikID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

PS: I also tried to insert values with

```
INSERT INTO Vlasnik 
VALUES ('xxxxx', 'xxxx', 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'xxxxx')
```

and it's working.

Comment: That error and SQL don't appear to be directly related. The above SQL doesn't have a single `-` character (post has been edited, I am referring to the definition of the SP specifically). It sounds like the error is with how you're trying to execute the SP, not the SP itself. We need to see the code you're using the `EXECUTE` the stored procedure as well.

Comment: i have used graphical interface for execution, here is code
 `DECLARE @return_value int,
  @VlasnikID int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[UbaciVlasnika]
  @ImeVlasnika = N'Petar',
  @PrezimeVlasnika = N'Petrović',
  @DatumRodjenja = 1897-03-20,
  @JMBG = 2003897710341,
  @VlasnikID = @VlasnikID OUTPUT

SELECT @VlasnikID as N'@VlasnikID'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value`
@marc_s

Comment: That should be in your question, not a comment.

Comment: @StefanSakic this is unreadable in comments. Please use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58289220/edit)

Comment: It should be `DECLARE @return_value int, @VlasnikID int EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[UbaciVlasnika] @ImeVlasnika = N'Petar', @PrezimeVlasnika = N'Petrović', @DatumRodjenja = '1897-03-20', @JMBG = 2003897710341, @VlasnikID = @VlasnikID OUTPUT SELECT @VlasnikID as N'@VlasnikID' SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value` at least, if executing in SSMS

Comment: `@DatumRodjenja = 1897-03-20` looks wrong. That would mean you're setting the value of `@DatumRodjenja` to the **`int`** `1894`; and you can't convert an `int` to a `date`.

Comment: I also thought so, so I tried with apostrophe and got error converting data type numeric to int. That when I got confused @Larnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing this via the GUI, you need to use single quotes around the date you input, e.g., `'2019-10-08'`.

If you take a look at the code in the resulting query editor, you'll notice that if you don't add the quotes, it will look something like:

```
@DatumRodjenja = 2019-10-08
```

This causes the "Incorrect syntax near '-'." error.

Also, the value you have specified for the `int` parameter is too big for the `int` data type, you may need to look into using `bigint`.

Comment: I mentioned that I tried that also but then i got error converting data type numeric to int even if my column and SP parameter was date format.

Comment: damn i missed that, i changed it on table but i guess i forgot to do it in sp. thank you @chris

Comment: You're welcome - please mark the answer as correct if it's working.

Comment: Code stops at date parameter so it doesn't reach that line of code at all

Comment: I have to apologize to you, guess i didn't put apostrophe when i tried to execute sp after changing `@JMBG` parameter to `bigint`. That was a problem with that gave me error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should always list the column names when you are doing an `INSERT`:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[UbaciVlasnika] (
    @ImeVlasnika nvarchar (50),
    @PrezimeVlasnika nvarchar (50),
    @DatumRodjenja date,
    @JMBG int,
    @VlasnikID int OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Vlasnik (ImeVlasnika, PrezimeVlasnika, DatumRodjenja, JMBG)
        VALUES (@ImeVlasnika, @PrezimeVlasnika, @DatumRodjenja, @JMBG);

    SELECT @VlasnikID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END;  -- UbaciVlasnika
```

I am guessing what the column names are.

Clearly, you are not inserting into all the columns, because one of them is the identity column.  I'm not sure why you are not getting an error that says that you have the wrong number of parameter values.  Perhaps SQL Server checks types before it counts all the values.

Comment: thank you for advice, I changed it but I'm still getting same error.

Comment: I don't get error for wrong number of parameters coz identity parameter is `OUTPUT`

Comment: @StefanSakic . . . Are you sure that your values are in the same order as the columns, and that the types are the same?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually in your GUI. The code should really look something like this (C# used for example):

```cs
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("UbaciVlasnika", "connstr");
    cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImeVlasnika", "some text");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrezimeVlasnika", "some text");

    //ATTENTION! parse the string to date type; don't pass a string into to a date type parameter
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatumRodjenja", DateTime.ParseExact("2019-01-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    //OR IF YOU ALREADY HAVE A DATE
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatumRodjenja", myDateTimePicker.Value);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JMBG", 12345);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@VlasnikID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    con.Open();
    int returnCode = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Output was " + (int)cmd.Parameters["@VlasnikID"].Value);
```

In the client side app we parse the parameters explicitly, to ensure that we're passing the right datatype to the server, rather than relying on implicit conversion. The db server might be in a different region to the app that is calling this procedure and hence have a different notion of how dates are formatted. The client app should always do the donkey work of parsing the argument, unless you change the signature of your procedure so it accepts a varchar and specifically convert the date inside the procedure - I'd avoid doing this for aforementioned reasons about the front end knowing/caring about regions and localisation and culture etc whereas the back end db can/should remain ignorant of these things

If you're using SSMS to quickly test this SP, do this:

```
DECLARE @return_value int;
DECLARE @VlasnikID int; 
DECLARE @im NVARCAHR(50) = N'Petar';
DECLARE @pv NVARCAHR(50) = N'Petrović';
DECLARE @dr DATE = '1897-03-20'; --or CONVERT(date, '1897-03-20', 20)
DECLARE @jm INT = 2003897710341; --this is way larger than int's max value 2147483647 - change it!

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[UbaciVlasnika] @ImeVlasnika = @im, @PrezimeVlasnika = @pv, @DatumRodjenja = @dr, @JMBG = @jm, @VlasnikID = @VlasnikID OUTPUT;

SELECT @VlasnikID as VlasnikID, @return_value as ReturnValue
```

Note that you're trying to stuff ~2 trillion into an int, whose max value is ~2 billion

---

Disclaimer: For clarity, when I said "should look something like this" I mean to treat this as pseudocode example - not that this was the perfect ideal code that should be copypasta'd straight into your production system.

Here I'm making the point to **convert your data in the client, not rely on the implicit conversion on the server**. I'm not specifically advocating use of AddWithValue; AWV makes for a great way to write some nice clean, simple parameterization code for a SqlCommand as an example on SO, though it opens up [a Pandora's box](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) of its own - consider whether you want it in a production system. It matters less with stored procedures because the parameter type that is used inside the procedure is defined in the procedure signature rather than inferred from the type inferred from the .net type passed to AddWithValue so I'm more relaxed about it's use with SPs to the point where I don't usually draw attention to it unless people start pitchforking about it

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you there. But, I'm back on the db check coz i was getting error for the wrong number of parameters and then I went be to db and stumble onto this.

Comment: Although an SP, just wondered; why did you chose to use `Parameters.AddWithValue` here, instead of `Parameters.Add`?

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @smor Yes indeed, I've read the blog (and the more lengthy "can we stop..."), recommended it a hundred times; it matters far less if you're using an SP

Comment: @larnu Brevity; footnote added

Comment: yes I'm using c# for this sp. and have identity class with DateTime prop in it, that is connected to datePicker and I'm using using directive for connection and command with parameters.AddWithValue. I'm parsing on the click event when im picking up from datePicker `v.DatumRodjenja = DateTime.Parse(PickerDatumRodjenja.Text);` but the problem is on the server. My sp isn't inserting values at all. no matter how I try. I tried YYYY-MM-DD; 'YYYY-MM-DD'; I even tried YYYYMMDD that should give you an idea how desperate I am :S -@CaiusJard

Comment: If you have a datetimepicker then you just use its `.Value` which gives you the selected date as a DateTime object - you don't datetime.parse its `.Text`. If you're trying to get this working in SSMS as a test, see the edit to the answer